# Incorrect glyph scaling in my terminal emulator

Tags: c++, rendering, glyph

I'm writing a terminal emulator in C++20, just for fun
My objective is to make an exact *DOS VGA text mode* emulation (**80x25** characters), but I want to let the user choose the window resolution. I'm using a 1280x720 window for my tests, and the font used is **ModernDOS8x16.ttf** (monospace). For rendering, I'm using SDL2 library with my custom OpenGL 3.3 code

Here are the important parts of my code

```
class Grid
{
    public:
        // ... omitted
        
    private:
        // Total environment dimension in pixels
        // (in this case, the size of the window)
        int m_envWidth, m_envHeight;

        // Number of cells
        int m_numCellsX, m_numCellsY;

        // Width and height of each cell
        // (in pixels)
        float m_cellWidth, m_cellHeight;
};

void Grid::initFromNumberOfCells(int numCellsX, int numCellsY)
{
    m_numCellsX = numCellsX;
    m_numCellsY = numCellsY;
    // Calculate the size of each cell with floating point precision
    m_cellWidth  = static_cast<float>(m_envWidth)  / static_cast<float>(m_numCellsX);
    m_cellHeight = static_cast<float>(m_envHeight) / static_cast<float>(m_numCellsY);

    this->makeCellRectangles();
}

void Grid::makeCellRectangles()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < m_numCellsY; y++)
    {
        const float posY = static_cast<float>(y) * m_cellHeight;

        for (int x = 0; x < m_numCellsX; x++)
        {
            const float posX = static_cast<float>(x) * m_cellWidth;

            m_cellRects.push_back({ posX, posY, m_cellWidth, m_cellHeight });
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me a cell size of 16x28.8 px

```
// A single character in the framebuffer
struct alignas(4) Character
{
    // Codepoint in UTF-32
    std::uint32_t codepoint{ 32U };
    // Foreground/background color
    std::uint16_t fg{ 15U }, bg{};
};

// Main framebuffer class
class Framebuffer
{
    public:
        // ... omitted
    
    private:

        // Emulated terminal size in
        // number of columns and rows
        // Default: 80x25
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_text_mode
        Size<int> m_terminalSize;

        // Array of character information
        std::vector<Character> m_framebuffer;
};

// Write a single character at the specified position
void Framebuffer::putCharacterAt(std::uint32_t codepoint, std::uint16_t fg, std::uint16_t bg, int x, int y)
{
    // Get the index that corresponds to the cursor position
    auto index = static_cast<std::size_t>((m_terminalSize.width * y) + x);

    // Put the character there
    m_framebuffer[index] = Character{ .codepoint = codepoint, .fg = fg, .bg = bg };
}
```

This works fine. The problem is in the character rendering. I want each character to be rendered *inside a grid cell, to be centered, and to have a proper size*. My bitmap font is baked at a bigger size, so I must scale it down. But I can't figure out how exactly should I do this. I'm currently getting a ratio and using the maximum value for the scale, and it works fine for some characters like 'a', but not for others like 'i' or ';' (screenshot at the bottom of the post)

```
void Framebuffer::renderSingleCharAtCell(const BitmapFont& font, Character character,
                                         const Texture2D& textureSprites,
                                         const Rect<float>& cellSize, const ColorPalette<16>& palette,
                                         PrimitiveProcessor<Quad>& processor,
                                         VertexBatch& batchText, VertexBatch& batchSprites) const
{

    // If the glyph is not found, replace it with a question mark
    if (!hasGlyph(font, character.codepoint))
        character.codepoint = 63U;

    // Get glyph data
    const auto& glyph = getGlyphData(font, character.codepoint);

    // Easy to remember-shortcuts
    const auto& glyphSize = glyph.uvCoords;

    // Calculate a ratio between
    // the glyph and the cell sizes
    const Vec2 glyphRatio
    {
        glyphSize.width  / cellSize.width,
        glyphSize.height / cellSize.height
    };

    // Picked the maximum
    float picked = std::max(glyphRatio.x, glyphRatio.y);

    // Draw rectangle for this glyph
    // These are the sprite coordinates where it should be rendered
    Rect<float> glyphRect
    {
        cellSize.x,
        cellSize.y + cellSize.height - (static_cast<float>(glyph.bearingY) / picked)
        glyphSize.width  / picked,
        glyphSize.height / picked
    };

    // Get font texture
    auto& fontTexture = *font.getTexturePtr()

    // Get color indices
    auto fgColorIndex = static_cast<std::size_t>(character.fg);
    auto bgColorIndex = static_cast<std::size_t>(character.bg);

    // Render the background
    processor.addPrimitive(batchSprites, { cellSize, opengl::calcNormalizedUV(textureSprites, WHITE_BOX_RECT), palette.getColorAt(bgColorIndex) });

    // Manually render the glyph inside the cell
    processor.addPrimitive(batchText, { glyphRect, opengl::calcNormalizedUV(fontTexture, glyph.uvCoords), palette.getColorAt(fgColorIndex) });

}
```

My question is: How should I calculate the correct proportion for each glyph?
Here are my results so far:

[image: terminal]

Comment: You say it's not working fine, but in the screenshot it looks like it's doing exactly what you described. The `i`, semicolon, apostrophe,  and comma have been scaled up to fully fit inside the box. There is no bug, this is merely your algorithm. if you want different results, then you need a different algorithm. https://imgflip.com/i/7gfo83

Comment: You are right, I've edited the question. Now it is: How should I calculate the correct **proportion** for each glyph?

Comment: The right question is: How should you calculate the correct proportion *for the font*.  My naieve guess would be to calculate the `max(width('W')/tileWidth, height('W')/tileWidth)`, because `W` should use the full width and height of each tile (similar to `em` units in javascript). And then use that same ratio for the entire font.  But my knowledge of font rendering is pretty basic.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)

Comment: It worked very well. Now I need to figure out how to center some characters, thank you. New screenshot here: ![Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/SJujxxE.png)

Comment: I just noticed that some characters like '@' exceeds the cell size. Maybe I need to iterate over every character to find the one with the maximum width and height in the font, and take it as a reference for scaling

Comment: Sidenote, you might want to calculate as if the boxes are one pixel thinner/shorter, so that way you get an empty pixel between adjacent letters.